# Unknown UTF-8 character in PERL

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, perl-module

I want to read string from text file in perl

The method I used to read is :

```
my $indPara = "C:\\Users\\Admin001\\Desktop\\paraText.txt";
open(INDPARA, $indPara) || die "Indesign paraText not found on location!";
my $indesignPara = <INDPARA>;
close INDPARA;
```

When reading the text, I am getting an unknown unicode character (`&#65279` or `&#xFEFF`) at the starting of text,

Download the text file that I used to read from below link

```
https://mega.co.nz/#!r1pAyAhA!VSnL2tbPWoTtThcCRoiogSxK4ok_0YvZSczs054w0uU
```

I am using Komodo IDE 8.5 and perl 5.16.3

kindly give some idea to overcome this

Thanks in advance

Vimal

Comment: Looks like encoding UTF-16LE, the Byte-Order-Mark `U+FFFE` (a zero-width space to mark Unicode variants). Try with an encoding capable editor like JEdit or NotePad++. It can be removed; is redundant. Used by Windows NotePad to distinghuish between ANSI and Unicode.

Comment: Dear Joop My need is Im reading this in perl So I want to clear it in perl itself, I dont wont to view it in any capable editor, though Im using Notepad ++ to view this, please provide any idea if you have and thanks for your comment

Comment: Then what is the problem you are facing? You seem to be able to read the file. You see the character you do not know because it is there (despite being zero width and as such invisible in editors not specifically showing it). Nothing wrong with Perl then. If it bothers you, you can remove or ignore it.

Comment: By the way, you can even see it is there in the normal windows editor. Move your cursor to the very left, hit left cursor again so you are on the left side of the zero width space and then hit right cursor. You will notice you need to move right twice to get past first visible character.

Comment: Dear DeVadder, When I read this in perl i cant cant remove this that is the problem, U can try with the textfile which i provided in above download link for your reference; Thanks, please share any idea you have, It might help to clear this

Comment: I can see that we have to hit twice to past the first character, but i dont know how to find that character in perl and remove it; DeVadder

Comment: Please explain what your problem or task is. I suppose the code snippet above does work, right? Or does it crash at some point? What is it that you are trying to do, that fails because of the character. And if nothing fails, why is the character a problem in itself?

Comment: Dear DeVadder, My program in to match this textfile content with another HTML file which has the same content; when i read the HTML with same content i didnt get any invisible character but reading this text file will get invisible character, so my matching is conflicting

Comment: @JoopEggen: The BOM is redundant only if the encoding is specified separately, out of band

Comment: Thank you So much guys for your kind help and ideas I found a way to clear this, ie: just find and replace this s/\x{feff}//g; and it works !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you So much guys for your kind help and ideas I found a way to clear this, ie: just find and replace this `s/\x{feff}//g;` and it works !

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It is telling you that what you have is not a UTF-8 file, it is a UTF-16 (BE) file).

The BOM is not part of the data in the file, so you can safely just skip past it and continue to read the data beyond it. However, you should not treat the data that you are reading from the file as UTF-8, you should treat it as UTF-16 (BE) and [decode it](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) appropriately.

Comment: Sure it is not UTF16-LE? U-FFFE would be in Little Endian: 0xFE, 0xFF.

Comment: I'm no expert, but the Wikipedia article I linked to says that 0xFEFF is Big Endian and 0xFFFE is Little Endian. This is 0xFEFF, so I assumed it was BE.

Comment: Bytes { x, y } should be in LE: x + 256*y and in BE: 256*x + y. And the BOM is U+FEFF, (not U+FFFE as I thought), so you are right.

Comment: Thank you So much guys for your kind help and ideas I found a way to clear this, ie: just find and replace this s/\x{feff}//g; and it works !

Comment: Why thank us for our help when you completely ignore our advice? The BOM is telling you something important about your data. Don't just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

If you would have the entire string (`$indesignPara`), do:

```
$s = decode("UTF-16LE", $s, Encode::FB_QUIET);
```

but I am not sure `<INDPARA>` works though. You could try `"<:encoding(UTF-16LE)"` as first extra parameter to open. And then strip the first wide character, the BOM U+FFFE.

Comment: The wikipedia and @DaveCross correct me, the BOM is U+FEFF, and the encoding should be **UTF16-BE**.

Comment: Thank you So much guys for your kind help and ideas I found a way to clear this, ie: just find and replace this s/\x{feff}//g; and it works !